# Java export as runnable JAR file from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I want to export my project as runnable JAR file but when I export it, it crashes automatically... also it takes only 900 KB which is too low for my program... What should i do?

Comment: Does it show any errors? (Run it from the command line to give more information, quite possibly.)

Comment: You need to tell us more information. How do you export it, what error does it give when it crashes, what is the contents of the MANIFEST file etc..

Comment: Are you using any build management tool as apache ant or apache maven?

Comment: I would really recommend something like Maven combined with th Shade plugin.

Comment: It doesn't give any errors, it creates JFrame but it doesn't show a picture in it (but it should)

Comment: Does it work if you start the app from within eclipse?

Comment: Yes, when I run it from Eclipse it works normally....

Comment: How to run it from command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run it from the commandline with

```
java -jar yourjarfile.jar
```

Is your picture located as a ressource in your project. Otherwise it's missing in the jar file  and so you may got an error